# Whats the best max/min resolution for a website?

Tags: html, web, resolution

I have been creating a website for a client.  I was using a laptop that was about 1280 by 800 in resolution.  The website looked fine at that size.   I just recently moved over to a desktop with a monitor nearly reaching 2000 in resolution.  The website no longer looks that great.  Is there a standard or a suggested max and min width/height for the body of a website?  If someone were to view this, it would look unprofessional.  What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Look up responsive web design.  Then learn how to use Bootstrap.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming problem, but a visual/interactive-design question. http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks bro, had no clue theres a dedicated visual stack exchange site

Answer (score 0):

Use `%` instead of pixels for defining the `width`of your page elements.

Something like:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="siteWrapper">
        <div class="header">
            ....
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            ....
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            ....
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

html, body {
    width:100%;
}

```
.siteWrapper  {
    width:100%;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #333;
}
```

The above `siteWrapper` class will extend according to the screen width, which is 100% of the width and add a padding of 50px on either side. You can follow the same approach with the inner child divs and their elements too to achieve a responsive look.

This is just an example of course so the padding pixels, width percentages, background-color, etc are just random values kept for explanatory purposes.